# Custom UIView with custom XIB: IBOutlets not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, xib

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I want to use a custom XIB in a custom UIView.

My custom UIView:

```
@interface CoordinateView : UIView {
    /**
     */
    ARGeoCoordinate *geoCoordinate;
    /**
     */
    IBOutlet UILabel* title;
    /**
     */
    IBOutlet UILabel* subTitle;
    /**
     */
    IBOutlet UIImageView* image;
}
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation CoordinateView

@synthesize geoCoordinate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Initialization code.
        //
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CoordinateView" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CoordinateView class]])
            {
                [self addSubview:currentObject];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initForCoordinate:(ARGeoCoordinate *)coordinate
{
    self.geoCoordinate = coordinate;
    CGRect theFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

    self = [self initWithFrame:theFrame];
    if (self)
    {
        title.text = geoCoordinate.title;
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"03%d.jpg", geoCoordinate.id]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

To initialize `CoordinateView` I use `initWithCoordinate` method.

Debugging I've found that `title` is nil here inside `initWithCoordinate`:

```
title.text = geoCoordinate.title;
```

I've used Interface Builder to 'link' IBOutlets.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a while back. Here is what I did to fix it:

1. In the xib, open the document outline (the left pane that shows the list of views and their subviews etc).
2. Control left Click on the view representing your class (in your case CoordinateView) and drag the blue line down to the subviews (in your case the UILabel called title)
3. XCode should then bring up a small dialog box with the option "title" (because your label is called title.)
4. Click on title and wallaa.
5. Go back to your debugging and check if your outlets are still nil.

Just a personal preference (not necessarily related to the topic on discussion): I would call your UILabel 'titleLabel' instead of 'title' because [objectInstance title] looks like it would return an NSString to someone who does not know that 'title' is a UILabel. Just a personal preference, thats all.

Cheers

Comment: The problem still exist with XCode 9 and iOS 11, but the dialog box in step 3 doesn't. Could you please update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

In your `initWithFrame:` method, you should assign `self` to `currentObject` instead of adding it as a subview.

Also there's no need to override `initWithFrame:` and calling the `super` method since the layout of your view is determined by your xib file.

Comment: In my project I had done what you are suggesting and everything worked perfectly, until a time came when I had to add an NSMutableArray as a property for my UIView subclass (lets call it MyCustomView). I alloc and initialised the array in MyCustomView init methods. But somehow while the app is running the array would mysteriously become nil. I tried adding it as an iVar but still the same problem persisted. I then googled and found the method of adding the view loaded with loadNibNamed to self (self being an instance of MyCustomView). That somehow worked. Any ideas on what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score -3):

When the view is totally loaded, the `viewDidLoad` method is called. So, you should initialize the elements within the view there:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    title.text = self.geoCoordinate.title;
}
```

More info in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: viewDidLoad is a UIViewController method, and I'm not using UIViewControllers.

Comment: How did you load your xib file without UIViewController?